# definite integral with incomplete gamma function and exponential

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, special-functions, gamma-function

While working with electron density computations in quantum chemistry, I encountered the following improper integral:
$$
I(k, n) = \int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n},\ k r^n\right) r \exp(-k r^n) dr
$$

I tried to solve it using integrations by parts, and I got the following equation:
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n},\ k r^n\right) r \exp(-k r^n) dr  =
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)}{n k^{\frac{2}{n}}} + k^{\frac{1}{n}} \int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n},\ k r^n\right) r^2 \exp(-k r^n) dr
$$

Repeating the integration by parts leads to $0=0$:
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n},\ k r^n\right) r^2 \exp(-k r^n) dr   =
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)}{n k^{\frac{3}{n}}} + k^{-\frac{1}{n}} \int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n},\ k r^n\right) r \exp(-k r^n) dr
$$

Using the substitute $u=kr^n$, I obtained:
$$
I(k, n) = \int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n},\ k r^n\right) r \exp(-k r^n) dr = \frac{1}{n k^\frac{2}{n}}\int\limits_0^\infty u^{\frac{2}{n} - 1}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n},\ u\right) \exp(-u) dr
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n},\ k r^n\right) r^2 \exp(-k r^n) dr = \frac{1}{n k}\int\limits_0^\infty u^{\frac{3}{n} - 1}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n},\ u\right) \exp(-u) dr
$$

Using WolframAlpha, I obtained the following closed forms for the following $n$-s:

| $n$ | indefinite $I(k, n)$ | definite $I(k, n)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\frac{1}{3}$ |  | $\frac{183013425}{16 k^6}$ |
| $\frac{3}{8}$ |  | $\frac{307643 \Gamma\left(\frac{40}{3}\right)}{652046560 k^\frac{16}{3}2^\frac{1}{3}}$ |
| $\frac{3}{7}$ |  | $\frac{8120681 \Gamma\left(\frac{35}{3}\right)}{4830232576 k^\frac{14}{3}2^\frac{2}{3}}$ |
| $\frac{1}{2}$ |  | $\frac{8595}{8 k^4}$ |
| $\frac{3}{5}$ |  | $\frac{3571 \Gamma\left(\frac{25}{3}\right)}{347776 k^\frac{10}{3}2^\frac{1}{3}}$ |
| $\frac{3}{4}$ |  | $\frac{365 \Gamma\left(\frac{20}{3}\right)}{10472 k^\frac{8}{3}2^\frac{2}{3}}$ |
| 1 | $\dfrac{1}{8k^2}\left(\exp[-2kr](5+10kr + 10k^2r^2 + 4k^3r^3 - 8\exp[kr](1+kr)\Gamma(3,\ kr))\right)$ | $\dfrac{11}{8k^2}$ |
| 2 | $ \dfrac{\Gamma\left(1,\ k r^2\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2},\ k r^2\right)}{2k}+\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} erf\left(\sqrt{2k}r\right)}{8k} - \dfrac{r\exp[-2kr^2]}{4\sqrt{k}}$ | $ \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{16k}(4+\sqrt{2})$ |
| 3 | $-\frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},\ kr^3\right)(2k)^{-2/3}$ | $\frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)(2k)^{-2/3}$ |
| 4 |  | $\frac{5}{4k^\frac{1}{2}}\left(\ _2F_1\left(-\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, -1\right) - \ _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, -1\right) \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)$ |
| 6 |  | $\frac{1}{2k^\frac{1}{3}}\ _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{5}{6}, \frac{4}{3}, -1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)$ |
| 9 |  | $ -\frac{2}{9k^\frac{2}{9}}\ _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{9}, \frac{5}{9}, \frac{11}{9}, -1\right)\Gamma\left(-\frac{4}{9}\right) $ |

Is there a hope of either finding the antiderivative or, at least, a closed-form for $I(k,n)$?

**UPD**: There is a closed-form for $I(k,n)$, obtained from a Russian book on integrals and series[1]:

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty x^{\alpha - 1}\exp[-px]\Gamma(\nu, cx) dx = -\frac{c^\nu\Gamma(\alpha + \nu)}{\nu p^{\alpha + \nu}}\ _2F_1\left(\nu,\alpha+\nu,\nu+1,-\frac{c}{p}\right) + \frac{\Gamma(\nu)\Gamma(\alpha)}{p^\alpha}$$

In my case, upon substituting $\alpha = \frac{2}{n}$, $p=1$, $\nu = \frac{3}{n}$, and $c=1$, I got:
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty u^{\frac{2}{n} - 1}\exp[-u]\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n}, u\right) du = -\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n} + \frac{3}{n}\right)}{\frac{3}{n}}\ _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{n},\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n},\frac{3}{n}+1,-1\right) + \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) = \frac{n\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{n}\right)}{3}\ _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{n},\frac{5}{n},\frac{3+n}{n},-1\right) + \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)$$

And finally:
$$
I(k, n) = \int\limits_0^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n},\ k r^n\right) r \exp(-k r^n) dr = \frac{1}{ k^\frac{2}{n}}\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{n}\right)}{3}\ _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{n},\frac{5}{n},\frac{3+n}{n},-1\right) + \frac{1}{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\right]
$$

[1] Прудников, Брычков, Маричев: Интегралы и ряды. В 3 томах. Том 2. Специальные функции; ISBN 5-9221-0324-5; p.134, eq. 2.10.3.2.